# Cross domain session, same application (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net

How can i preserve session between domains? They all belong to the same asp.net-application.

Comment: As [Shoban](http://stackoverflow.com/users/12178/shoban) answered below, simply add <httpCookies domain=".usa.com"/> to your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without a custom implementation.  Your session id is stored in a cookie in the browser and it is sent back to the server with each request.  That's how the server knows who you are and which session object is yours.  When you switch domains, the browser no longer sends this cookie (cookies are sent per domain, so the server will never see the original session cookie and therefore generate a new session cookie for the new domain).

I don't know the architecture of your app related to when the user goes from one domain to the other, but you may just be able to send a common cookie to the browser each time the user accesses each domain for the first time and use this to correlate an in-memory object on the server.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you have the multiple domains specified in the host header for the website that is hosting the application and the application resides in an application pool that is not using any form of web garden it will be served by a single worker process w3wp.exe. As long as your web.config has not specified the session to be stored outproc rather than inproc then session data will be available to all code residing within your application.